# Using DateRangePicker how to apply time picker only for one day?

Tags: jquery, css, daterangepicker

I have created one demo using daterangepicker and it's working fine.
Now I want to apply time picker also with daterangepicker. But I want time picker only for one day. When user select date from the calendar and go for the date range select start to end date then time picker automatically hide from the calendar.
For Eg: User select 06-07-2018 to 07-07-2018 or 06-07-2018 to 10-07-2018 then Time picker want hide.
User select one day for start to end date then time picker show. 
For Eg: User select 06-07-2018 to 06-07-2018 then Time picker show.
I have right now manually initialize time picker using css manually hide.

This is my html code:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title></title>
  <style type="text/css">
  .daterangepicker .left .calendar-time{
   display:none !important;
  }
  .daterangepicker .right .calendar-time
   {
    display:none !important;
   }
</style>
```

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/daterangepicker/daterangepicker.css" />

<div>
    <input type="text" id="dates" name="dates" value="" />
</div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery/latest/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/momentjs/latest/moment.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/daterangepicker/daterangepicker.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {            
        $('input[name="dates"]').daterangepicker({
            minDate: new Date(),
            timePicker: true,
       });       
       });       
</script>
```

Right now My date picker show look like:

[image]

After I have right css which I have give above in head tag then date picker show at that time time picker not show first time.

Using css My date picker look like:

[image]

In above screencap my time picker is hide.

Now I want when user click on same start to end date then my time picker automatically show and when user go for select date range start to end date then automatically hide.

I want this on mouse click.

Any one know how can do that. how to get dates on mouse click.

Eg: User select 06-07-2018 to 06-07-2018 then time picker show
    User select 06-07-2018 to 07-07-2018 to n dates then time picker hide.